# Capturing longitude and latitude coordinates on 'pageshow' with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, geolocation

I am writing an iOS app where the app must determine the current latitude longitude each time a page loads. I need to access the longitude and latitude from the event handler and pass the latest coordinates to a third party server.

I have been able to retrieve the coordinates using Cordova's `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` but need help to:

1. Capture the coordinates each time a page loads
2. Append the coordinate values to a GET request on an external URL.

so the question is simply can someone please advise me the correct syntax to be able to capture the value generated in the getlocation script below so i can have the co ords appended to the url so coords= the long / lat values generated

Here's my pageshow event handler code:

```
$("#HomePage").live("pageshow",

                    function() {
                    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
                    $.get("http://[externalurl]/process.cfc?method=HomePage&CORDS=[LATEST COORDS VALUE]]&returnformat=json", {}, function(res) {
                          $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                          var s = "";
                          for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
                          s+= "<li><a href='employeedetails.html?Id=" +  res[i].Id + "'>Employee Details</a></li>";
                          s+= "<li><a href='OrgDetails.html?OrgId=" +  res[i].OrgId + "'>OrgDetails</a></li>";
                         }
                          $("#HomePageContent").html(s);
                          $("#HomePageContent").listview("refresh");
                          },"json");
                    });
```

Below is the code I'm using to retrieve the users current coordinates. I just need to figure out how I can get the values into the jQuery function above so they can be appended to the GET request.

var x = document.getElementById("demo");

```
              function getLocation() {
              if (navigator.geolocation) {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
              } else {
              x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
              }
              }

              function showPosition(position) {
              x.innerHTML = + position.coords.latitude +
              "," + position.coords.longitude;
              }
```

Comment: I assume from your code example where you've assigned an event handler for the pageshow event, that you are using jQuery Mobile. I've updated the title and tags for your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues to correct:

First, the `$.live()` method was deprecated long ago and was completely removed from jQuery in version 1.9 ( http://api.jquery.com/live/ ).

Second, the jQuery Mobile `pageshow` event is also deprecated and will be removed with the release of jQuery Mobile version 1.6 ( https://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/ ).

Your event handler for capturing when the page is shown, should look like this:

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
   var elmtId = $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop('id'); 

    if (elmtId == "HomePage") {
       // YOUR CODE HERE
    }
});
```

There is nothing preventing you from executing the `getCurrentPosition` method from directly inside the `pagecontainershow` event handler above.

It could be as simple as this:

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
   var elmtId = $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop('id'); 

    if (elmtId == "HomePage") {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude 
                             + ',' 
                             +  position.coords.longitude;
        }, function(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        });
    }

});
```

You will want to ensure that `#HomePage` does refer to the jQuery Mobile page and *not* and an element inside the page. jQuery Mobile pages have the `data-role="page"` attribute on their outermost element ( http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/pages/ ).

Comment: pagecontainer events can't be attached to page div - except for page create - they should be attached to document. Your code won't work.

Comment: @Omar It would appear from the jQuery docs that there is more than one way to capture the `pagecontainershow` event. The jQuery Mobile docs ( http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/ ) provides an example essentially identical to mine above:  `#event-show $( ".selector" ).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {} );`  Either way, I've updated my answer to show how it would be done if the `pagecontainershow` event were captured at the document.

Comment: Thanks Eliot, i wil make those mods to the live vs on etc Aas advised, however when i use your suggested code re long / lat it generates the following error 

Error in Success callbackId: Geolocation262329345 : TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'element.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude + ',' +  position.coords.longitude')

can you also advise the correct reference to use to apend the values to the url

Comment: @Claudio I would recommend running a `console.log` on both the `position` variable and `element` variable before you set the `innerHTML`. One of those two variables is not being set properly.

Comment: Hi when i debugged from my phone via safari and ran the page the error i provided to you earlier was what presented in the consol log so i am not sure where to go from here

Comment: @ElliotB. try it as per the doc, would your code run? :)

Comment: elliot, sorry which doc are u referring, so there is no confusion i am wanting to get this co ords working as required before i start changing the .live to .on etc given i am not yet running jquery 1.9 code